# Meaning of Eigenvalues/Eigenvectors of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalue, linear-systems

I have a 41x41 system of linear equations (inhomogen) which I derived with Eureqa by describing the timecourse of fMRI haemodynamic data from a brain area as a function of the timecourses of 40 other brain areas (from Brodmann areas). The person who was measured had to do some specific task and had seen some pictures. So the timecourse data is a function of the stimuli and my equations somehow also describe the stimuli.

e.g.

brainarea1= f(brainarea2,...,brainarea41)
brainarea2= f(brainarea1,...,brainarea41)
...
brainarea41=f(brainarea1,...,brainarea40)

(See this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/equations_all.txt) here for the equations)

So..now I can solve this linear system, can compute the eigensystem for example..

but my question is..

1. What would a physicist do with such a system. What is the straightforward way to analyze such a linear system of equations? Also, which Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors are of interest?

   What would they mean is this case, when I for example take the Eigenvector of the biggest Eigenvalue? In other words: What does the Eigenvector tell me about the system?
2. Is it possible to extract the timings when the person saw some stimuli from the system or somehow extract more information about the stimuli, when I know the exact time a stimuli occurred (which I do know)? Since the data of the timecourses is a function of what stimuli the person saw, one can see the frequency of the stimuli in the frequency domain if Fourier transform is applied.
   But is there something else one can do with this system?
3. What would change if my system is a nonlinear system of equations? Would there be some fundamental constrictions or limits in my possibilities to analyze the system?

I'm not hoping for some specific solutions to that matter, but maybe for some helpful hints and tips how to go deeper into it, maybe what I could read up on and so on.

Comment: You have 41 equations, but it's unclear what form they have. If you were to write them out in matrix notation, it looks like $M (B_1, \ldots, B_{41})^T = (B_1, \ldots, B_{41})^T$, where $M$ is 41 by 41 and has zeros on the main diagonal? Is this right?

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Yes. The system is in the form M x = b where M is my 41x41 matrix x is my column vectors of brainareas and b the constant values column vector. I'm not sure about the 0's in the diagonal since the original equations where of the form x1 = a*x2+b*x3... so I moved x1 to the right to get 0 on the left side. So I have -1 on the diagonal I guess..hmm im no physicist or mathematician so correct me, if I'm wrong :/

Comment: Usually such matrices represent a *transformation* of sorts. You have a black box that takes input $x$ and gives output $y$. You test it with different inputs. The $y$ that corresponds to an $x$ of $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ becomes the first column of $M$, etc. Once you've done this 41 times, you have the full $M$ such that (output) = M * (input). Then there are many directions to go, e.g. (1) fix an output and ask what then input must have been, (2) ask what inputs remain constant modulo scaling when acted upon, (3) ask what those scaling are...

Comment: As it stands, though, it *sounds* like you just have each quantity expressed in terms of the other 40, without reference to inputs and outputs. What is the difference between the column vector being multiplied by $M$ and the result of that multiplication? Perhaps I'm just misreading things, as I'm also not sure where time comes into play.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Thanks for your answers! I edited the post and put a link with the equations. They are no differential equations!

Answer (score 0):

For a square matrix ***M*** and a linear operator L the eigenvalues *f* are simply the solutions of the equation:

```
L*M = fM               (1)
```

This cannot be solved by cancellation, as in elementary algebra, as **M** is an n by n square matrix, while f is a scalar [ constant, or time varying if ***M*** is time varying ]

Equation (1) can be put more succintly as:

```
(L - f)  M = 0               (1a)
```

Generally f is a spectrum of *n* values where *n* is the dimension of the matrix, although two or more values may coincide.

For a matrix as large as yours there are libraries of numerical functions in Fortran and num.py to solve for the set of eigenfunctions *{f}*

If L was nonlinear eigenfunctions wouldn't exist, but if the non-linearity was small the equation could be solved using perubation methods, the same as in quantum theory. *warning - this is computationally expensive, involving squares and higher powers of M*.